# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wagtail'. How to fix this?

Tags: wagtail

I have tried to get wagtail up and running twice: once using the guide in  https://engineertodeveloper.com/wagtail-developer-portfolio/ and this time using: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.12.4/support.html.  Both times the error comes after:

```
python manage.py migrate

pip freeze shows:

anyascii==0.2.0
asgiref==3.3.4
beautifulsoup4==4.8.2
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
Django==3.1.8
django-filter==2.4.0
django-modelcluster==5.1
django-taggit==1.4.0
django-treebeard==4.5.1
djangorestframework==3.12.4
draftjs-exporter==2.1.7
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
html5lib==1.1
idna==2.10
l18n==2020.6.1
openpyxl==3.0.7
Pillow==8.2.0
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.25.1
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
tablib==3.0.0
urllib3==1.26.4
wagtail==2.12.4
webencodings==0.5.1
Willow==1.4
xlrd==2.0.1
XlsxWriter==1.3.9
xlwt==1.3.0
```

So I have installed wagtail (latest version)

Comment: From further discussion in the Wagtail support slack, it looks like this was caused by to this person not exactly following the instructions and using the same folder name for both the virtualenv and the project. Voting to close as typo...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Tibor at Slack, python sometimes becomes confused.  Solution was to use

```
python -m pip
```

instead of just

```
pip
```